# Doctor: “There’s a $50\%$ chance of surviving this procrdure” Patient: “Let’s do it twice”

Tags: probability

Inspired by this
[image]

What is the chance of survival? 25% or 33%?
Assume the doctor **will** perform the procedure two times, given that the patient survives the first one.

Comment: 25% it is! is it clear to you why?

Comment: @Simonsays one could say that there are 3 possible scenarios: live-live, live-die, die. That makes only 1/3 of them desirable

Comment: @technology and the third one has probability $0.5$, while the first two have each probability $0.25$. It's not because you define 3 events that they are all equiprobable.

Comment: @amWhy I have updated the question to clarify that aspect.

Comment: Notice that all the comments and answers until now have implicitly assumed that the probabilities are independent, in the sense that, if there is a second procedure, the probability of surviving it is still 50%, unaffected by the fact that the patient survived the first procedure. That assumption is a good, natural, mathematical simplification, but unlikely to be true in real life.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your comment, you mentioned $3$ potential outcomes:

- Live - Live
- Live - Die
- Die

This may seem like living twice is $33\%$, but notice that the third outcome, die, has a $50\%$ chance versus the other two at $25\%$. This is because you have a $50\%$ chance success rate (and thus $50\%$ death rate) on the first surgery.

The other two are $25\%$ because you have $50\% \cdot 50\%$. This of course makes some assumptions about living in the first place and the independence of events.

And as CogitoErgoCogitoSum points out, **if you assume that the surgeon always performs the second surgery** then you can increase the probability to $50\%$ because that eliminates the possibility of death on the first surgery giving you two equally possible events on the second surgery.

Comment: Note though that in the third bullet, "Die", the procedure only happened once. So the doctor didnt fulfill his promise to do it twice.  So this is not even a legitimate possibility under the condition that the procedure was done twice.  "Live-Live" and "Live-Die" are the only two permissible outcomes under the conditions. Ergo 50% is the answer.

Comment: @CogitoErgoCogitoSum I agree. Initially, I wrote the post before that edit, and was addressing the OP's comment.

Answer (score 0):

Imagine a tree structure. Then you have a 0.5 chance to live. If you live, you will have again a 0.5 chance to die. So by using the path rule you multiply them and get 25%

Answer (score 0):

Round 1 = live or die

50/50 chance to make it to round 2

Round 2 = live or die

50/50 chance to live

25%

No different than the probability of flipping a coin twice and landing two heads (consecutively 2 heads is 50/50) ...

EDIT:

I also wrote some code (in PHP) to demonstrate the visual.

```
$live = 0;

for ($i = 0; $i < 10000; $i++)
{
    $procedure1 = (bool)rand(0,1);

    if ($procedure1)
    {
 $procedure2 = (bool)rand(0,1);

        if ($procedure2)
        {
     $live++;
        }
    }
}

print($live/10000);
```

If I run that actual routine 10,000 times, I get right at 25% every time.